# Elasticsearch not_analyzed field still finds on search

Tags: elasticsearch

I create an index with a mapping which contains a field `not_analyzed` with command below and index a document with next command.

```
 curl -XPUT localhost:9200/twitter -d '{
"settings": {
"number_of_shards": 5,
"number_of_replicas": 1
},
"mappings": {
"tweet" : {
    "properties" : {
        "message" : {   "type" : "string", 
                        "index": "not_analyzed"}
    }                      
  }
  }
}'


curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet?' -d '{
"user" : "kimchy",
"postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
'
```

I checked to mappings with `http://localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping?pretty=true` and it outputs:

```
 {
 "twitter" : {
"mappings" : {
  "tweet" : {
    "properties" : {
      "message" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "post_date" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "user" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
  }
 }
}
```

Finally when I search with this `http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty=1&q=trying` it finds the indexed document. Is it normal? I thought it should not find it unless I search the complete text `"trying out Elasticsearch"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not_analyzed` means that it's not doing tokenizing/other analysis to index the values, but it does still store the full value in Elasticsearch and it can be used as an exact match in a terms query.  The field value is still getting included/analyzed into the `_all` field and indexed there so that it's searchable.

You need to set `"include_in_all": false` or `"index": "no"` to disable that.

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html for more information.